# Using Ninject create an instance of an interface

Tags: c#, reflection, kernel, ninject

In our middleware, interfaces are bound in `Global.asax.cs`.  I created a `HandshakeInvoker` that reflects through all `FieldInfo` until it finds an interface that implements `IESFPingable`.  When it finds one i need to create an instance of that interface which will then call the ping() class in the provider.  My problem is I am having trouble creating the interface once it finds a match.

`Global.asax.cs` binds:

```
kernel.Bind<IAccountProvider>().To<AccountProvider>().InSingletonScope();
```

`HandshakeInvoker`:

```
public object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs)
{
    outputs = new object[0];
    Type interfaceType = typeof(IESFPingable);

    FieldInfo[] fields = serviceType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (FieldInfo f in fields)
    {
        if (interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  >> Field {0} Implements {1}", f.fieldType.Name, interfaceType.Name);
            var interfaceToPing = kernel.Get<f.FieldType.Name>();
        }
    }
    return DateTime.Now;  //return date for now
}
```

I get errors:

> The Name 'kernel' does not exist in the current context and The type
>   or namespace name 'f' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive...)

Does anyone see what i am doing incorrectly?  All help greatly appreciated.

EDIT: We use Ninject to instantiate our interfaces. I am told i should need to use kernel.Get.  The reflection returns the interface as a string (f.FieldType.Name), which throws errors in Get. But besides that it doesn't matter what i put in kernel.Get.  I get a type or namespace error.  I've tried to do 
   Type myType = Type.GetType(f.FiedlType.Name) and put kernel.Get and it gets the same error.  I've tried a hundred different things and so have others with no luck.  I've been told that the Generic answer this post referred me to does not use Ninject and will not work here.

I just need to call a methodin a provider class in another assembly.  The Interface/Provider is included in the bindings in the Global.asax but no matter what we try it doesn't work. I am very frustrated.  Do I need to use DependencyResolver?  Is this not even possible?  It has to be possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works much better.  I didn't need to create a new instance of the interface.

```
    public object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs)
    {
        outputs = new object[0];

        Type interfaceType = typeof(IESFPingable);
        Type T = instance.GetType();
        FieldInfo[] fields = T.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var f in fields)
        {
            var result = f.GetValue(instance);

            if (result is IESFPingable) 
            {
                (result as IESFPingable).Ping();
            }
        }
        return DateTime.Now; //temporary
    }
```